# How to create a logic repetition for branch root on php

Tags: php, repeat

i wondering to create a logic repetition for repeat and make a branch on php, the result will be like this (this is without repetition logic just html) :

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Child</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              </li><li>
                <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Grand Grand Child</a>
                  </li><li>
                    <a href="#">Grand Grand Child</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li><li>
            <a href="#">Child</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Grand Grand Child</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li><li>
                <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You mean, "recursion"

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix if you create with a recursion, how to create 2 branch, and each branch have a derivative? i feel it's must be create with repetition

Comment: I don't usually do recursion on holiday weekends.  To do repetition, you would need to know the max number of levels beforehand, recursion is < infinite.

Comment: Say you have a function `buildItem()` when you hit a child you call `buildItem()` from within `buildItem()` and build that sub-tree

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix can you give me an example?

Comment: No, not without some Idea on how you are storing the child parent relationship.

Comment: Here, toward the end is a couple examples ... http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2012/08/php-adjacency-list-hierarchy-tree-traversal.html  Under "Retrieving Nodes"  You have to understand what you are asking is not trivial, and requires a lot of thought into the data structure you use to store the tree, I suggest reading some tutorials on it  search for something like this in google "hierarchical data php".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by using a recursive function, and a nested array which you then traverse through. The following function could go n levels deep without issues.

```
<?php
function makeNav($item) {
    $ret = '<li><a href="'.$item['url'].'">'.$item['name'].'</a>'.PHP_EOL;

    if (isset($item['subPgs']) && is_array($item['subPgs']) && count($item['subPgs']) > 0) {
        $ret .= '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($item['subPgs'] as $subPg) {
            $ret .= makeNav($subPg);
        }
        $ret .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $ret .= '</li>'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (isset($item['subPgs']) && is_array($item['subPgs']) && count($item['subPgs']) > 0) {
        $ret .= "</li>".PHP_EOL;
    }

    return $ret;
}

$navItems = array(
    /*array(
        'name' => 'Home',
        'url' => '#',
        'subPgs'=>array()
    ),*/
    array(
        'name' => 'Parent',
        'url' => '#',
        'subPgs' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Child',
                'url' => '#',
                'subPgs' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Grand Child',
                        'url' => '#'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Grand Child',
                        'url' => '#',
                        'subPgs' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'Grand Child Child',
                                'url' => '#'
                            ),
                            array(
                                'name' => 'Grand Child Child',
                                'url' => '#'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Child',
                'url' => '#',
                'subPgs' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Grand Child',
                        'url' => '#',
                        'subPgs' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'Grand Grand Child',
                                'url' => '#'
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Grand Child',
                        'url' => '#'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$nav = '<ul>';
foreach ($navItems as $navItem) {
    $nav .= makeNav($navItem);
}
echo $nav.'</ul>';
?>
```

**Outputs: (which matches OPs, except formatting)**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Grand Child Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Grand Child Child</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Grand Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**See it online:** https://3v4l.org/O4i2t

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that if your data set is large or the code gets more complex than just a simple text string in each list element you may want to cache the results of your recursive function and only rebuild the tree when the data is updated.

I would pass the current parent id in if I knew I could access each parents children through some other function. Recursion is always tricky and deceptively simple when it works.

```
// assuming getChildIds( $parentId ) is a function that returns an array of ids
// assuming getName( $id ) is a function that returns a name. 
// If you actually want "Parent", "Child", ... "Grand Grand ... Grand Child" 
// add a generation parameter to the recursive function and figure it out that way.

function echo_child_node( $parentId ) { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><?php echo getName( $parentId ) ?></a>
        <?php $childIds = getChildIds( $parentId ); ?>
        <?php if ( $childIds ) : ?>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach( $childIds as $childId ) :
                echo_child_node( $childId );
            } ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
   </li>
<? }
```